# Add a new off-topic close reason for nonsense question

Tags: feature-request

I was looking for the best closing choice for [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26668396/the-best-premium-wordpress-themes-wordpress-themes-2014) (this is even not a question) 
and could find a proper response among the propositions
![image]
What do you think about adding a "nonsense / not a question" closing reason ?

Comment: I see no requirement for a new close reason for that question which the current close reasons cannot cater for. What is wrong with "off-topic" or "unclear what you're asking"?

Comment: I cannot see a valable off-topic proposition, what would you have choosen ?

Comment: apt close reason for this question is "unclear what you're asking "

Comment: Does "Blatantly off-topic (this question has nothing to do with programming)" not stir your beans?

Comment: You can type your own off-topic reason. But this is an edge case where someone attempts to spam but somehow the link is missing.

Comment: @James That option does not exist for users with >3000 rep. Instead they can write their own close reason.

Comment: @Antony or use "unclear.."

Comment: yes I suppose I could have used "unclear..." in that case

Comment: While being as precise as possible is always key, I think in some cases, as with this one, using the best option that matches is fine just to get the pointless/stupid question closed. Even if not perfect for the scenario, it's a terrible Q so likely not going to be edited. probably deleted by the OP soon..

Comment: @Antony I was searching a existing proposal without the need to add any comments. (Am I too lazy friday morning ?)

Comment: Question is now deleted an invisible to users with less than 10k rep, so it's pretty difficult to have an opinion about it.

Comment: @ivarni it was some sort of spamming attempt where the link had been (i guess) automatically removed by SO

Comment: @Kayasax You can try [my userscript](http://stackapps.com/questions/4483/close-reason-editor-customize-your-off-topic-close-reasons) then.

Comment: @Antony thanks, will have a look

Comment: Would probably be better to flag it as spam than try to find a close reason. With a spam flag, a moderator can handle it directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's a waste of time.  That question was *blatantly* spam, and was likely flagged as such.  Any questions that appear to be similar to that should be downvoted and flagged as well.

Remember - closure isn't about punishing users for a bad question, it's to (eventually) [help a user get their question in a good enough shape](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/06/the-war-of-the-closes/) such that it can be reliably answered.  Flagging a question for spam accomplishes two things:  it gets the question off of the main page (by virtue of automatic downvotes), and it also expedites its removal from the site entirely.  With enough of those posts, the account would be removed as well.